# Redirect to show page after creating an add

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have an app where users can create a pproperty add through the store route. If this is successful i want to use return redirect to follow the route that controls the show page. The route is /property/id

These are the store, and show controllers.

```
  public function store(Request $request, $id){
      $Advert = new PropertyAdvert();

      $Advert::create(
        [
          "photo"       => base64_encode(file_get_contents($request->photo->path())),
          "address"     => $request->address,
          "county"      => $request->county,
          "town"        => $request->town,
          "type"        => $request->type,
          "rent"        => $request->rent,
          "date"        => $request->date,
          "bedrooms"    => $request->bedrooms,
          "bathrooms"   => $request->bathrooms,
          "furnished"   => $request->furnished,
          "description" => $request->description
        ]
      );

    return redirect('/property/id');
    }

    public function show($id){
      $user = Auth::user();
    $Advert = PropertyAdvert::where('id', $id)->first();
    return view('pages/Advert/show', compact('Advert', 'user'));
  }
```

Just using /property/id doesn't seem to work, as it does in the routes when you type it in.

Routes
    Route::post('/createadvert', 'AdvertisementController@store');

```
Route::get('/property/{id}', 'AdvertisementController@show');
```

Comment: So, when the user hits create advert, it will send something to that right? and after the advert is created, you wanna redirect to the property/id page, returning the propert advert?

Comment: When the user creates the advert, all the data is sent to the database, then I went to redirect to a show page (ie a blade template) to display the infomation. I have the template working if i manually naviagate to /property/id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
public function store(Request $request){
    $Advert = PropertyAdvert::create([
        "photo"       => base64_encode(file_get_contents($request->photo->path())),
        "address"     => $request->address,
        "county"      => $request->county,
        "town"        => $request->town,
        "type"        => $request->type,
        "rent"        => $request->rent,
        "date"        => $request->date,
        "bedrooms"    => $request->bedrooms,
        "bathrooms"   => $request->bathrooms,
        "furnished"   => $request->furnished,
        "description" => $request->description
    ]);

    $id = $Advert->id;

    return redirect("/property/$id");
}

public function show($id){
    $user = Auth::user();
    $Advert = PropertyAdvert::where('id', $id)->first();
    return view('pages/Advert/show', compact('Advert', 'user'));
}

?>
```

::create works on the class, not on the class instance.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function store(Request $request){
      $Advert = new PropertyAdvert();

      $new = $Advert::create(
        [
          "photo"       => base64_encode(file_get_contents($request->photo->path())),
          "address"     => $request->address,
          "county"      => $request->county,
          "town"        => $request->town,
          "type"        => $request->type,
          "rent"        => $request->rent,
          "date"        => $request->date,
          "bedrooms"    => $request->bedrooms,
          "bathrooms"   => $request->bathrooms,
          "furnished"   => $request->furnished,
          "description" => $request->description
        ]
      );

    return redirect('/property/'.$Advert->id);
    }
```

Comment: My issue here is that I get an error that says too few arguments. 1 passed, 2 expect. When I take out $id, the error is Undefined variable: new

Comment: remove `$id` in your function param plz check answer